# Ploting a Histogram

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I need to plot a histogram for the data below, country wise quantity sum.

```
     Country         Quantity
0   United Kingdom   4263829
1   Netherlands      200128
2   EIRE             142637
3   Germany          117448
4   France           110480
5   Australia        83653
6   Sweden           35637
7   Switzerland      30325
8   Spain            26824
9   Japan            25218
```

so far i have tried this but unable to specify the axis myself:

```
df.plot(x='Country', y='Quantity', kind='hist', bins=10)
```

[image]

Comment: `bins=10` will create 10 evenly spaced bins that span the entire range of your data. Given the max is 4M your bins are rougly 0-400K, 400k-800K, With so few observations across such a large range of values a histogram doesn't seem like the correct visualization

Comment: so do you mean it is working fine but due to huge difference in range of elements some of them just have very less value and cant be observed?

Comment: Yes, many of those bins have no countries with a quantity within the range. A bar plot will plot a bar for each country, with the height indicates the **magnitude**. A histogram instead groups similar magnitude values into a bin and plots the **frequency** of those observations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.bar(df['Country'],df['Quantity'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: i need countries on x axis

Comment: It should give you countries on the X-axis and the sum of quantities of respective countries on the Y-axis.

Comment: Histogram with countries on X-axis, and frequency on the y-axis is the number of occurrences of that country in your data. It wont take into consideration the 'Quantity'. Unless you have data list where each of your 'Country' is repeated 'Quantity' times, then passing such a data to a hist() function would render a plot that you want, explicitly using a hist() function.

Answer (score 2):

Try a [bar plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html) instead of a plot:

```py
df.bar(x='Country', y='Quantity')
```

Comment: I know bar plot works fine, but i need to do hist on this one

Comment: @DhruvNautiyal Do you want the countries on the x-axis?

Comment: Good. And what do you want on the y-axis? The values from your 'Quantity' column? If so, that's exactly what is in my answer.

Comment: Did you try to run my answer? Isn't that what you want?

Comment: i know using bar it works fine and also gives the desired output, i want to know how we can do the same with hist

Comment: Hist does an histogram of the values you give.  If you have 10 bins from 0 to 4 millions, the first bin goes from 0 to 400,000. Nine out of 10 values end up in the 1st bin, and one in the last bin, which is what you plotted in the question. I don't understand what else you expect.

Comment: See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.hist.html for the histograms from dataframes.

Comment: is it possible to plot the by position, for example not consider 1st row and plotting the rest

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211893/discussion-between-keldorn-and-dhruv-nautiyal).